# Help sorting Contacts by Account and then by Name

Tags: apex

I am tying to sort a list of contacts on an account. If >1 has Billing listed for a field, I only want the first alphabetically to keep the value. I am getting a slew of errors on line 21.

```java
public class ContactRoleManager {
    public static void updateBillingContact(List<Contact> contacts) {
        Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountIdToContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
        List<Contact> updatedContacts = new List<Contact>();
        
        // Iterate over all the contacts and check if any of them have the value 'Billing Contact' for the rtms__Transportation_Role__c field.
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if (contact.rtms__Transportation_Role__c == 'Billing Contact') {
                // If the contact is the billing contact for the account, add it to the map.
                if (!accountIdToContacts.containsKey(contact.AccountId)) {
                    accountIdToContacts.put(contact.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
                }
                accountIdToContacts.get(contact.AccountId).add(contact);
            }
        }
        
        // For each account that has multiple billing contacts, sort the contacts by contact name and update only the first one.
        for (Id accountId : accountIdToContacts.keySet()) {
            List<Contact> billingContacts = accountIdToContacts.get(accountId);
            if (billingContacts.size() > 1) {
                billingContacts.sort((a, b) -> a.Name.compareTo(b.Name));
                for (Integer i = 1; i < billingContacts.size(); i++) {
                    billingContacts[i].rtms__Transportation_Role__c = null;
                    updatedContacts.add(billingContacts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // If any contacts were updated, perform the DML operation.
        if (!updatedContacts.isEmpty()) {
            update updatedContacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my counting is right, then the problematic line is `billingContacts.sort((a, b) -> a.Name.compareTo(b.Name));`, which would make sense because that's definitely not valid syntax. Apex has no lambda/anonymous/arrow functions.

Comment: It also looks like you should go back and accept the answer that you got on your previous question. You don't _have_ to accept an answer, but it is part of the stackexchange culture (and it lets other people know that you don't need help on that one any more, and it gives you some reputation score as well).

Answer (score 0):

A few basic thoughts:

- The `if (!updatedContacts.isEmpty()) { <your dml here> }` is unnecessary. Salesforce is smart enough to not perform the DML (and not count it against you) if the list is empty
- You can save yourself a good deal of trouble if you use a SOQL query to do some of the heavy lifting

An incomplete (but mostly complete) implementation:

```java
// A fair number of things in Salesforce begin with gathering record ids
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact c :contactsList) {
    accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
}

List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
Set<Id> encounteredAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

// This query is the secret sauce
// You can base the query on Account and use a Parent-Child subquery to do the grouping
//   for you
// You can use a WHERE clause in the subquery to limit it to billing contacts
// You can use ORDER BY in the subquery to, well, order the results
//   (which is probably the thing that helps the most here)
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts WHERE rtms__Transportation_Role__c = 'Billing Contact' ORDER BY Name ASC) FROM Acccount WHERE Id IN :accountIds]) {
    // Yes, this is a nested loop
    // It's fine (and in fact, correct) in this context because we're only looping
    //   over the Contacts for the current Account (as opposed to over ALL Contacts
    //   for ALL Accounts)
    for(Contact c :acct.Contacts) {
        // we'll only get into this IF for the first Contact on each Account
        if(!encounteredAccountIds.contains(acct.Id)){
            encounteredAccountIds.add(acct.Id);
            continue;
        }

        c.rtms__Transportation_Role__c = null;
        contactsToUpdate.add(c);
    }
}
```